# Can I omit If() statements if they are only used to check a condition for a while() loop?

Tags: c, if-statement, optimization, while-loop

Saw this in a solved excercise. Isn't the `while` loop already a conditional? Is it better to use both the `if` block and the `while` loop even if I don't need a `else` statement afterwords?

```
int main(void) {
    int foo = 10;

    if (!foo) {
        while (!foo) {
            foo--;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would write that code this way:

```
int main(void) {
    int foo = 10;

    while (!foo) {
        foo--;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: That can't have been the **whole** code, because what you show is pointless. Perhaps there was another operation which should be done *once only* when `!foo`.

Comment: I made this bit of code up just as an example. The actual code is much bigger than this, but the transcription of the relevant part is accurate (the way the `If` conditional is used). I know this code is in fact pointless, I just wanted to simplify it since my question is directioned towards a little thing.

Comment: Did you mean `!!foo` ?...  because as is the block is skipped.

Answer (score 2):

Yup. If is redundant. In first version you check the same thing 2 times for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

On some implementations, there may be a performance difference between:

```
if (x) do
  ... loop body
while(x);
```

and

```
while(x)
  ... loop body
```

The former, for example, may translate to:

```
START:
  if (!x) goto EXIT;
  ... loop body
  if (!x) goto START
EXIT:
```

while the latter would yield either:

```
START:
  if (!x) goto EXIT;
  ... loop body
  goto START
EXIT:
```

or

```
  goto LOOPEND
LOOPSTART:
  ... loop body
LOOPEND:
  if (x) goto START
```

In the version with the `if`, the zero repetitions case contains one branch taken, and the N repetitions case will contain N-1 branches taken and two branches not taken.  The first alternate version, the zero repetitions case will have one branch taken, while N repetitions case will contain N unconditional jumps and N-1 branches not taken.  In the second alternative version, the zero-repetitions case will have one unconditional jump and one branch not taken, while the N repetitions case will contain one unconditional jump, N branches taken, and one branch not taken.

The version with the `if` would generate larger code, but would execute fewer instructions than either of the straightforwardly-generated alternatives.  Modern compilers might "optimize" both versions of the source code into the same machine code, which may or may not represent the best time/space trade-off for what the programmer is trying to do.